# Assignment of Multiple Variables ("a,b = c,d" vs "a = c , b = d")

Tags: python

when working with online problems I ran into an issue in this section of code:

```
    while list1 and list2:               
        if list1.val < list2.val:
            tracker.next = list1
            list1, tracker = list1.next, list1
```

This works just fine, but when I simply rearrange it for readability into:

```
    while list1 and list2:               
        if list1.val < list2.val:
            cur.next = list1
            list1 = list1.next
            tracker = list1
```

I run into a timeout error and I cannot see how such a simple change can do this.

Am I missing something? or is the change in time drastic enough to affect the program?

Comment: `tracker` became `cur` in the second version. That doesn't look equivalent with the limited context you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple rearrangement. The second example has a different logic, i.e. in the first snippet `list1` is changed to the value of `list1.next`, and `tracker` is changed to the value of `list1`(before it was changed to `list1.next`). While in the second example `tracker` is changed to the value of `list1` **after** `list1` is changed to `list1.next`. In other words `list1` and `tracker` are always the same.